# executing r script from MySQL

Tags: mysql, r

We wanted to use MySQL to store data, for processing we are using R programming. Is there any way of calling R script from MySql stored procedure, we can execute R script fro MSSQL, but we want to use MySQL.

If anyone know the solution, it will be a great help

Answer (score 0):

Not currently. Check back later this year on the Graal Project which will let you embed stored procedures in your MySQL Server and is in test currently